# Sharing Cookies and/or authentications

Tags: authentication, sharing

Is it possible for more than one site to share a cookie or create a "global" cookie for multiple sites to access? They share the same domain but have different subdomains.

We have several systems and need a way to share authentication between them. When a user is logged into one, we want them to also be logged in to the others.

One site is authenticated through Magenot as it is our e-commerce site. one is through Wordpress as it is our content and the other is an ASP.Net site. They all authenticate to an Oracle back end through a web service but how would I be able to tell if a user is logged into one of the others and if they are, log them into the one they are accessing?

Anyone know how to do that handily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie can be set for a domain or subdomain, so yes, you can have a global cookie by setting it to your top level domain. In this case you would need to configure each system to use the top level domain for their authentication cookie and the same cookie name.

However, The different systems are going to use different content and encryption for their cookies so I don't think they can share a cookie in the way you intend.

Comment: We own all the source code so why wouldn't we be able to rewrite the authentication stuff to all match?  Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: You are right you could probably write custom authentication modules or plugins for each system.